# Weird character inserted when pasting with mouse in mobaxterm terminal

Tags: terminal, mobaxterm, charset

Example of weird character insertion:

[image]

I get an error because an extra weird character got sent :  ▒

My mobaxterm terminal is in utf-8, version 20.2. Windows 10 21H2

It happens when I paste with the right click from my desktop to the terminal.

Maybe I should file a bug directly at moba..

Thanks for reading !

Edit : just upgraded to the latest version of Mobaxterm 22.0 and still have the same problem

To clarify, my problem is : "how do I avoid inserting weird characters when copy pasting from windows to the mobaxterm terminal using the mouse ?"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run this command:
printf "\e[?2004l"

Comment: Please explain why